# getting a google analytics access token and how to use it in google sheets script

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-sheets, google-analytics-api

I am currently pulling data from the API query URI from the query explorer from google. https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ It's possible here to include a 60 minute access token.

Now I want a non expiring access token and gotten as far as the API Project website from google and I have generated a client id and secret.

I tried to add the client_id and client_secret as parameters to the url like so:
url&client_id=xxx&client_secret=yyy

This does not work.

How can I generate a working access token in Google (Sheets) scripts?

Thanks

Comment: I might understand wrong what you are after, but if you enable the Google Analytics service via the script editor (service must also be enabled in the API console) then you can make the script run as the active user (or the owner if it runs unattended via a trigger). That would take of authentication and so you would not need a token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to start at the beginning.

To get an Access token you need to use a client id and client secret to request access of a user.   When the user grants your application access then you will be given an access token.  A good place to start [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)

Usage:

> RestRequesturl?access_token=[yourtoken]

When you request access of the user you send scopes with it scopes denote what access your application will need.  There is a large list of scopes for Google [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)  in your case you will need to request the scope for Google analytics and the scope for google sheets this will allow you to access both the user google analytics account and their Google Sheets.

As you know access tokens expire after an hour for that you need a refresh token a refresh token will allow you to request a new access token of the authentication sever without having to request access for the user again.  I am not a JS developer but i know you can get a refresh token with node.js but i don't think you can with pure js.

I have a tutorial series that may help you get up to speed. [Google development for beginners](http://www.daimto.com/google-development-beginners/) reading the one on Oauth2 would probably help you.  [Google Developer console oauth2](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-oauth2/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have got it working by using the build in Google Advanced Google services. After enabling this the authentication gets done by drive itself and not by my code. I'll approve your answer since it's a valid solution at my original question. Thanks